# If and else condition running together

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have written a simple for loop with an if-else block inside it for an android app.
The code looks like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ques.length; i++) {
                    int attempt=0;
                    int j=i+1;
                    ans1 = t.getText().toString();
                    if (ans1.equals(ans[i])) {
                        qView.setText("");
                        t.setText("");
                        aview.setText("");
                        if(j!=ques.length) {
                            aview.append("Attempts: 0");
                            qView.append(ques[j]);
                        }
                        else
                            qView.append("Congrats!You have completed the quiz");
                    }
                    else {
                        attempt++;
                        aview.setText("wrong");
                        //aview.append("Attempts: " + attempt);
                    }
```

When I run the app and enter the correct answer to match the if condition, the commands `t.setText("")` and `qView.setText("")` get executed, however for aview,
the command under `else (aview.setText("wrong"))` gets executed. Why is this happening? How is it possible that both if and else blocks are being executed for the same input?

Comment: They must be happening under different iterations of the loop. Step through your code and find out why.

Comment: *If and else condition running together* not possible at all it must be logic flaws

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE in any circumstances

Comment: How long is array ques? What is the contents of ans[0]? Of ans[1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:

```
break;
```

after

```
qView.append("Congrats!You have completed the quiz");
```